# Please help me to understand line of code of kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

**This Is Interface**

```
interface Callback {
  fun onFilterSelect(filter: Filter)
}
```

**Adapter**

```
class FilterAdapter(
    private val context: Context, 
    val callback: (filter: Filter)->Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterAdapter.ViewHolder>() {}
```

Please help me to understand this line of code

```
recyclerView.adapter = FilterAdapter(view.context) {
  mCallback?.onFilterSelect(it)
}
```

I want to use this kotlin code in my java project

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). There is a convention that you should specify a lambda outside of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Java8 code for this kotlin code can be like as following:

**This is interface**

```
interface Callback {
    void onFilterSelect(Filter filter);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
class FilterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private FilterAdapter() {};

    FilterAdapter(Context context, Function<Filter, Void> callback) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

And finally initialize adapter:

```
recyclerView.adapter = new FilterAdapter(context, filter -> {
        callback.onFilterSelect(filter);
        return null;
    });
```